# Are iPhone replacements for software issues free?

Tags: iphone, repair

iPhone 6 is not under warranty (no Apple Care+ either), but Apple Support on the phone offered a replacement phone that I pick up at the store (no mention of cost, did not ask) because of an issue with the phone that I did not cause (no physical damage). So, will this be a complimentary iPhone replacement or will it cost money like a screen repair?

**Edit:** It was, in the end, replaced free of charge.

Comment: AFAIK it's up to the discretion of Apple Store staff whether it's free or not. It could well be a replacement fee of a couple of hundred $$ if it's out of warranty, but I've had luck before with Apple staff pulling strings for me. In short, it depends - be nice, and patient, with the staff and they might help you :)

Comment: Software issues can always be resolved with an iOS restore.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson Mine was not resolved with an iOS restore; I think it was really a software/hardware interaction that was causing my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be free. I had an iPhone 6 replaced for free just last month. The iPhone was 6 months out of warranty, no AppleCare, but was having battery problems. Apple determined the battery was defective and replaced it for free.

Comment: We had similar with an iPhone 5. Started playing up, took it to Apple, they just gave us another. Most of the time, they really do like to keep their customers happy; but there's never any guarantee.

Comment: @TimMalone It ended up being free! Thanks for all your advice.

Comment: I wonder how they determine batter was defective? My iPhone 6 goes from 37% to 1% back to 37% sometimes.

Comment: @Sun that sounds like a software issue to me! Post a question of it!

Answer (score -1):

Apple Store will diagnose hardware/software and replace iOS software at no charge.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.